# Why does the getline call glibc's malloc instead of __wrap_malloc when passing `-wrap=malloc` to the linker?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, malloc, hook

When I try to pass `--wrap=malloc` to the ld linker for hooking `malloc`, I find that `getline` will not call `__wrap_malloc`, but call glibc's `malloc`.

```
// foo.c
void* __wrap_malloc(size_t sz) {
   printf("abc");
   return __reall_malloc(sz);
}

int main() {
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t n = 0;
   getline(&line, &n, stdin);   // will call malloc
   ....
}
```

Run as:
`$ gcc foo.c -Wl,--wrap=malloc && ./a.out`
It doesn't print "abc", it seems that `__wrap_malloc` isn't called.

But run as:
`$ gcc -static foo.c -Wl,--wrap=malloc && ./a.out`
I got a segment fault, print the backtrace:

```
#0  0x00000000004490e7 in vfprintf ()
#1  0x0000000000407a76 in printf ()
#2  0x0000000000400ab7 in __wrap_malloc (size=1024) at foo.c:26
#3  0x0000000000456a2b in _IO_file_doallocate ()
#4  0x000000000040d4a5 in _IO_doallocbuf ()
#5  0x000000000040c4d8 in _IO_new_file_overflow ()
#6  0x000000000040b421 in _IO_new_file_xsputn ()
#7  0x000000000044921f in vfprintf ()
#8  0x0000000000407a76 in printf ()
#9  0x0000000000400ab7 in __wrap_malloc (size=1024) at foo.c:26
....
```

It seems that `__wrap_malloc` (called in `printf` initally) is called recursively, which means that `getline` call `__wrap_malloc` instead of glibc's `malloc`.

What happened if `-static` passed to linker? How can I force `getline` call `__wrap_malloc` instead of glibc's `malloc`?

Comment: And you are not interested in hooks? https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html

Comment: What's in the stack backtrace from entry 10 upwards — to main?  Since `printf()` calls `malloc()`, you've created recursion, which probably doesn't lead to happiness?  Your `__wrap_malloc()` ends up being called before the `printf()` can complete — and before it (`__wrap_malloc`) allocates memory.  Try replacing `printf()` with `write(2, "abc\n", 4);` and see whether the world is a sunnier place afterwards.

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to keep both of glibc's `malloc` and my custom `malloc`. Modifying the `__malloc_hook` pointer or cover the weak symbol (such as `malloc_usable_size`) will lose glibc's `malloc` (or `malloc_usable_size`). How can I keep both of them? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `-static` is passed to the link editor, the link editor can see all internal calls to `malloc` and will try to wrap them, causing the infinite recursion because your own `malloc` implementation calls `printf`, which in turn calls `malloc` in some cases.

Without `-static`, the link editor cannot rewrite the internal `malloc` references within `libc.so.6`, so internal calls in glibc are never redirected.  There is no infinite recursion, but you do not see those internal calls, either.

glibc supports replacing `malloc` using ELF symbol interposition (as far as such a thing is possible):

- [Replacing `malloc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html)

You still need to be careful to avoid triggering infinite recursion, though.

Comment: I have tried this method [replacing_malloc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Replacing-malloc.html). However, what I I want is that glibc's `malloc` and my custom `malloc` are both reserved after linking. Modifying the `__malloc_hook` pointer or cover the weak symbol (such as `malloc_usable_size`)  will lose glibc's malloc. How can I keep both of them? Thanks!